# How to I get the username of the currently logged in user in ASP.NET Core 2, not Application Pool details

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I appreciate that this question has been answered in the past but I'm unable to locate an up to date answer.

I'm getting user's details with the following:

```
string userName = UserPrincipal.Current.SamAccountName;
```

This works when running through VS. However on the server, it returns the Application Pool identity instead.

How so I get the users details instead?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Razor Pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username is always available via:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

You can also get it from the claim:

```
User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name)
```

If you're not in the context of something with the `User` property (controller/view/page), then you'll need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public Foo(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then:

```
var username = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity.Name;
```

`HttpContext` may be null, depending on whether you're in the context of an active request, so you'll need to compensate for that with a null check, if you're depending on the username.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on that a bit? Docs say ````User```` isn't available in Core 2.2.

Comment: What? Where'd you see that. `User` is certainly there. Has been, and probably always will be. I know for a fact it exists in Core 2.2, regardless.

Comment: Thanks, took a slight different approach but it pointed me in the right direction. Turns out I was looking at the wrong ````HttpContext```` in the docs.